# Editing a value in a ldap dn

Tags: ldap, openldap, syntax

What is the correct syntax to edit a value in an LDAP dn? As of now I was trying the following:

```
serveradmin@magic:~$ ldapmodify -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com <<EOF
> dn: uid=foo,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
> changetype: modify
> edit: loginShell
> loginShell: /bin/false
> EOF
```

However that returns the following error:

```
ldapmodify: modify operation type is missing at line 3, entry "uid=foo,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
```

So I'm assuming the `edit` is not a correct operation type. So what is the correct syntax to edit a users login shell?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to modify a entry is with the keyword `replace`. So in order to modify the login shell of the user, the command would look like this:

```
serveradmin@magic:~$ ldapmodify -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com <<EOF
> dn: uid=foo,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
> changetype: modify
> replace: loginShell
> loginShell: /bin/false
> EOF
```